# How do I make text fade off screen as you scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, opacity

I'm trying to make text fade off screen as you scroll. I was able to do it somewhat successfully but ran into an issue where all of the text disappears at the same time meaning once the text at the top goes, all the other text below it goes too.

Multiple HTML tags have the class "text". I tried to do each of the classes children separately but that didn't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
            $(".text").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have did with the help of making array of text and then add fade out effect for each text.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/fj3mtz8c/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.text').each(function(index) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > index * 5) {
        $(this).css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / ((index + 1) * 100));
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 50px;
}

body {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
<h1 class="text"> HELLOOOOOOOO</h1>
```